Does copyright law apply?
I wish to sell an item similar to one that a well-known international auction house had sold on a particular date.
Can I write this in my sales pitch or am I infringing on the auction house’s copyright?

For a copyright infringement, you would need to copy something, like the image they used for their advertisement or their advertisement text.

This question is light on detail and hard to answer as a result. What, if anything, is actually being copied?

Copyright exists to protect creative expressions from unauthorized copying.
Just stating a fact that a similar item was sold at auction at auction-house H for price P is not a violation of copyrights. On the other hand, re-using the auction-house's catalog listing in your sales pitch is a copyright violation.

Although copyright doesn't apply in this case (unless you were ripping off their ad copy word for word, perhaps), there might be a case against you under trademark law depending on what exactly you do. Specifically, while you can mention the fact that a particular auction house sold a particular item, you cannot do so in a way that implies any connection or endorsement from them, nor may you use their name or likeness to draw attention.
If, in several paragraphs of description, you happen to mention that X was sold by Y auction house for Z price, that would likely be fine.
But if you had, for instance, a banner reading "As seen on Y!" that was prominently displayed above the product, that might be seen as implying an endorsement or piggybacking on their fame to sell your product.

Not a copyright-related problem, but if the item is one where provenance/authenticity/quality etc. affect its value, then a seller may need to be careful with phrases like "X was sold by Y auction house for Z price" if that implies more/better about their item than is warranted.

@TripeHound True. I assumed the OP was right that their goods are substantially similar to the one previously sold, but they definitely need to be careful about that assumption.

The auction house typically wouldn't hold a copyright to the item. If the item sold at auction is protected by copyright and you copy that item, that is copyright infringement of the owner of the item's copyright.
Merely saying that the auction house sold a similar item, a factual statement not intended to show affiliation with, or endorsement by, the auction house, would probably not violate the auction house's trademark.
The auction house's copyright would be limited to the words and images that it generated in relation to the item. If you use your own words and images in your sales pitch, and don't use an image that the auction house has a copyright in, then you have not violated the auction house's copyright.
